How to call shortcodes on link or button press from a wordpress template
I have plugin that I wrote that adds a menu item to the Wordpress dashboard, which when selected, shows a template page that is coded in Templates/admin.php file.
This works, but now I am looking for an example of how to create a list of links or buttons that will call do_shortcode() for various functions from within the admin.php template.
I am currently creating a page for each with a shortcode call on it and using a sub menu item in the Dashboard to call that page, but I would really like to be able have a single control panel in Templates/admin.php verses sub-menu buttons that simply fire the shortcode via a page load.
<ul>
<li> do shortcode1 </li> // links to fire shortcode1, etc.
<li> do shortcode2 </li>
<li> do shortcode3 </li>
</ul>

I think the only way is to create a form that has various buttons which use the submit to calls a javascript function which then calls the do_shortcode('[shortcode1]') function.
I am thinking that there is a better way, but not sure. Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated.

You can create a WP Ajax handler that's going to render HTML code you need and return it or either create a JSON with the data you need to later generate the HTML code in JavaScript using this data. You don't need shortcodes for this, that's not why they were invented.

You can have a look at this WSE answer may help
